# How to resolve 'mdb-accordion' is not a known element: error in Angular app?

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I am trying to add the Material Design Bootstrap Accordion to my angular app using [this](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/accordion/#o-basic-accordion) example.

Here is my HTML:

```
<mdb-accordion [multiple]="false">
    <mdb-accordion-item [collapsed]="false">
      <mdb-accordion-item-head>Collapsible Group Item #1</mdb-accordion-item-head>
      <mdb-accordion-item-body>
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute,
        aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft
      </mdb-accordion-item-body>
</mdb-accordion-item>
</mdb-accordion>
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

> 'mdb-accordion' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mdb-accordion' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mdb-accordion' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ng(0)

Here is what I have in my Angular.json:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/mdb.scss",
          "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
          "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
          "node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
          "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
          "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"
         ]
```

And I have the following in my App Module:

```
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tried adding something like ***MDBootstrapAccordion*** to the import in App Module, but nothing was appearing.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing to get the accordion displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use MDB Free and `mdb-accordion` is not available in this version. You would need to purchase PRO version in order to use it in your project.

As you can see, there is a 'MDB Pro component' label in the documentation:

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/accordion/